# Does IPython support python version 3.2.3? If not, why?

Tags: python, django, ipython

I am currently working on a project that makes use of Python 3.2.3 and thought to do some tests of my code in IPython but it seems that IPython does not support the version of python I am using.

I get the following ImportError when trying to run Ipython on my Ubuntu machine.

```
ImportError: IPython requires Python version 2.7 or 3.3 or above.
```

Comment: I think that message is fairly explicit about whether or not it supports 3.2.

Comment: I understand the message. I wanted to know why my version of python is not supported, but thanks.

Comment: You can see from the release notes that IPython stopped 3.2 support from  v2.0: http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/2/whatsnew/version2.0.html#release-2-0-0

Comment: In python3.3 features were introduced that made supporting both python2 and python3 with a single code base much easier.

Comment: Yes I know about python 3.3 but my project is in 3.2.3, but I got the solution, so thank you guys.

Answer (score 3):

You can find some discussion about dropping 2.6 and 3.2 support [here](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/pull/4002). One of the main reasons was that 3.2 does not support 2.x-style unicode strings - `u"I love IPython!"`, while 3.3 and above do. This change made it possible to support 2.7 and 3.3+ in a single codebase.

Comment: Thanks! This was very helpful and the answer I was looking for.

Comment: @jetbird13 glad to help. If you feel this answered your question, feel free to mark it as [accepted](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) by clicking the check mark next to it.

Comment: Yep, the u prefix was the main reason that we dropped Python 3.2. BTW, if you want to use IPython with Python 3.2, you can get the last version that did support it by doing `pip install ipython<2`.

Answer (score -1):

[Quickstart](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/2/install/install.html):

IPython requires Python 2.7 or ≥ 3.3.

If you need to use Python 2.6 or 3.2, you can find IPython 1.0 [here](http://archive.ipython.org/release/).

PS:

The deadsnakes PPA has packages for old and new python versions:

```
sudo apt-get install python-software-properties
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:fkrull/deadsnakes
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install python3.3
```